# How can I use ajax actionlink in WebGrid's header

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid, actionlink

I'd like to sort the data in WebGrid by clicking the header of the column with some other parameters post to the controller, but the WebGrid's autosorting supply a fixed link on the column header with only two parameters.

I found some way to change the link address on the WebGrid's column header, but it works only on common links and not a ajax `ActionLink`, so that I can't use partial view to reflash only part of the webpage.

Can anyone help me to solve the question ?

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 2);
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "Contact``TB",headerStyle: "ContactHD",columns: grid.Columns( 
              grid.Column("ID", 
                          @Ajax.ActionLink("ID","Index","Home",new { pid = Model.PageIndex, sort=true},
                                           new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "grid", 
                                                             HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                                                           }
                                           ),
                           model.id,
                           ))

             );
```

The code up is the example effect I want to have, it's a wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can start with,

As you are able to generate common link, you can bind these links to a jquery ajax call to an action.

**Jquery Code**

```
function MyMethod() {
var url = '@Url.Action("GetData")';
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
data: { value: strId},

success: function (result) {
$('#result).html(result);
}
});
}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult GetData(string id)
{
return Json(new {foo="bar", ball="dragon"});
}
```

code taken from [here](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-an-action-from-javascript-or-jquery-in-mvc-3-razor/)